# How to transpose a group by SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server. I have written a query which generates a table group by department name. Each department have 3 teams - team A, team B and team C. The 3 teams are shown in column. However, I would like to show the 3 teams in rows group by department name. How can I achieve it? Below are my query and table out and desired output.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT
    Dept, 
    Dept_Name, 
    COUNT(team_A) AS 'Team_A',
    COUNT(team_B) AS 'Team_B', 
    COUNT(team_C) AS 'Team_C', 
    COUNT(team_A) + COUNT(team_B) + COUNT(team_C) AS 'Num_emp'
FROM 
    department 
GROUP BY 
    Dept, Dept_Name 
ORDER BY 
    Dept
```

Current output:

[image]

How to make my table look like this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried an [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Also on SO we prefer formatted text instead of images. And sample data as DDL/DML statements to allow people to copy/paste out the test data.

Comment: How does the data in 'department' look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Dale K. Thanks. I got it to work with `Unpivot`. I first created a view called 'DEPT_SUMMARY' for my original statement as it contains Alias. Then I use `unpivot`. Below is my answer:

```
SELECT a.[dept], a.[dept_name], a.[team], a.[num_count], a.[numuser] FROM [DEPT_SUMMARY]
      unpivot(
        num_count
        for team in (Team_A, Team_B, Team_C)
      ) 
a ORDER BY a.[dept];
```

Comment: Good work! Its good to see someone take some tips and solve the problem themselves :)

Comment: You can always accept your own answer I think which makes the solution useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I would unpivot *before* aggregating and do this in a single step:

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name, v.team, SUM(team_num) as team_num,
       SUM(SUM(team_num)) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Dept_Name) as num_emp
FROM department d CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Team_A', Team_A),
             ('Team_B', Team_B), 
             ('Team_C', Team_C)
    ) v(Team, team_num)
GROUP BY d.Dept_Name, v.team
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name;
```

There is no reason to create an intermediate table to do this.